# Show that the map $A(f) = \int_0^1f(x)dx$ defines a bounded linear functional on the normed vector space $(C[0,1], \| \cdot \|).$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and define a norm $\| \cdot \|$ on $C[0,1]$ by $\| f \| = \max_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)|.$
    Show that the map 
    $$A(f) = \int_0^1f(x)dx$$
    defines a bounded linear functional on the normed vector space $(C[0,1], \| \cdot \|).$

My attempt:

> For $f,g \in C[0,1],$ we have 
>   $$A(f+g) = \int_0^1(f+g)(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx + \int_0^1 g(x) dx = A(f) + A(g).$$
>   Therefore, $A$ is linear.
>
> Since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval $[0,1],$ by the Extreme Value Theorem, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [0,1].$
>   For all $f \in C[0,1]$ with $\| f \| \leq 1,$ we have $|A(f)| \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx \leq \| f \|.$
>   Therefore, $\| A \| = \sup\{ |A(f)| : \| f\| \leq 1\} \leq 1.$
>   Hence, $A$ is bounded.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: With respect to the linearity, the condition $A(\alpha f)=\alpha A(f)$ is also required.

Comment: With respect to the boundedness, in general we do not have the equality $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx = \| f \|$. Also, $\| A \| \neq \sup\{ A(f) : \| f\| \leq 1\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a lot of typos in my proof.

Comment: You forgot to show that $A(\alpha f)=\alpha A(f)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ in your linearity proof

Comment: @Idonknow If we ignore the typos, I think the unique thing we should change is the mention to the Extreme Value Theorem (as I explained in my post). The other change I suggested in the post is optional (as the restriction $\|f\|\leq 1$ was not used we do not need write it, but write it do not make your proof wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With respect to the linearity, the condition $A(\alpha g)=\alpha A(g)$ is also required.
- With respect to the boundedness, the mention to the Extreme Value Theorem is not needed (it is needed in the definition of the norm, which was done in a previous step). Also, the inequality $|A(f)| \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$ is valid for all $f\in C[0,1]$ and in general we do not have the equality $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx = \| f \|$. Finally, $\| A \| \neq \sup\{ A(f) : \| f\| \leq 1\}$.

So, I would rewrite your proof as follows.

> For $f,g \in C[0,1]$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$, we have 
>   $$A(f+\alpha g) = \int_0^1(f+\alpha g)(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx + \alpha \int_0^1 g(x) dx = A(f) + \alpha A(g).$$
>   Therefore, $A$ is linear.
>
> For all $f \in C[0,1]$, we have $|A(f)| \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx \leq \| f \|$. Therefore, $\| A \| = \sup\{ |A(f)| : \| f\| \leq 1\} \leq 1.$
>   Hence, $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Actually, for the linearity proof, wouldn't you want to show that $A(\alpha_1f + \alpha_2 g)=\alpha_1 A(f)+ \alpha_2 A(g)$ for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{K}$ ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik No. The equality I wrote is enough. For linearity we need $A(f+g)=A(f)+A(g)$ and $A(\alpha g)=\alpha A(g)$. This follows from $A(f+\alpha g)=A(f)+\alpha A(g)$ by taking $\alpha=1$, $\alpha=-1$ with $f=g$, and $f=0$. Of course, the equality you wrote also implies the desired (by taking $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ and $\alpha_1=0$).